# Forwarding ports with ssh on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, tcp, ssh-tunnel

I have a database server, let's call it:

**dbserver**

I have a web server with access to my dbserver, let's call it:

**webserver**

I have a development machine that I'd like to use to access a database on **dbserver**, let's call it:

**dev**

**dbserver** has a firewall rule set to allow TCP requests from **webserver** to **dbserver:1433**

I'd like to set up a tunnel from **dev:1433** to **dbserver:1433**, so all requests to 1433 on **dev** are passed along to **dbserver:1433**

My sshd_config on **webserver** has the following rules set:

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
```

This is what I've tried (from **dev**):

```
ssh -v -L localhost:1433:dbserver:1433 webserver
```

In another terminal (also from **dev**):

```
telnet localhost 1433
```

Results in:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please mark the solution as the answer, for the benefit of future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the solution I found:

```
ssh -v -L 1433:dbserver:1433 webserver -f -N
```

```
telnet localhost 1433
```

Connects me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -v -L 1433:localhost:1433 webserver
```

Comment: Found the solution, this was pretty close, but skipped one step.  Thanks for your help.